# NoUiSlider - doesn't hide lines

Tags: javascript, css, nouislider

I have NoUiSlider 12.1.0 in my CSS theme (modern admin) and it works fine, but there is some problem with CSS. When I move by handle the slider lines behind them are not hiding / changing color. Do anyone know what can cause the problem, or what class/styles I should check?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing any code, but the issue is likely in one of two things:

- You've set the `connect` option to `[true, true, true]` (where you want to have `[false, true, false]`). The booleans indicate whether the areas between the slider edges and handles should be colored.
- The `connect` option is set to `false` and you've styled the `background` of either `.noUi-base`, `.noUi-target` or `.noUi-connects`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have found, there are some styles affecting *.noUi-connects* class. This fixed my problem:

.noUi-connects {
    background-color: white;
}